# VSCode can't find files in Linux system

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, flatpak

I have installed `Visual Studio Code - OSS` via `flatpak`. I changed

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/zsh"
```

shell exist and working

```
$ which zsh
> /usr/bin/zsh

$ ls -l $(which zsh)
> -rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 865456 Feb  4 21:06 /usr/bin/zsh

$ zsh --version
> zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ echo $SHELL
> /usr/bin/zsh
```

When new terminal window is opened, and terminal window is closed right after following message is displayed in the terminal window.

```
execvp(3) failed.: No such file or directory
```

---

I again installed `vscodevim` plugin and configured

```
"vim.enableNeovim": true,
"vim.neovimPath": "/usr/bin/nvim"
```

But, i get following error message.

```
Configuration: Invalid neovimPath. ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/bin/nvim'.
```

But the nvim exist:

```
$ Configuration: Invalid neovimPath. ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/bin/nvim'.
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3383384 Jan 14 03:41 /usr/bin/nvim
```

VS Code failed to find the system files it seems. How can i resolve this?

```
> Flatpak 1.3.2
> Visual Studio Code - OSS com.visualstudio.code.oss 1.33.1 stable x86_64 flathub  user
```

Comment: Where is VSCode installed? Also, what permissions does the VSCode executable have?

Comment: It looks like flatpak runs vscode in a sandbox that prevents it from accessing the filesystem: http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html#filesystem-access Can you try launching with `--filesystem=host` or another appropriate flag from that link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could access "/usr/bin/zsh" in host by

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/run/host/usr/bin/zsh"
```

However there are many problems loading libraries and configurations from the home directory. So I assume it does not allow access everything in the files system. NOTE: This requires no additional parameters to `flatpak run`